# Manipulating data of dynamic html tags jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, class, src, attr

I have this code,

```
    $('#gogo').click(function(e){

    var data='<a href="http://www.google.com" class="myButtons">Google</a><a href="http://www.microsoft.com" class="myButtons">Microsoft</a>";
            $("#showResults").html(data);

    });


    $(".myButtons").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert($(this).attr("href"));
        $("#result").attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));
    });


<button id="gogo">Click me</button>

<div id="showResults"></div>

<iframe id="result" name="result" src="" width="750px" height="450px" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
```

I was wondering why it is not working. Perhaps is it because there is no event handler of new added html tags?

I don't want to use a target="result"

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not binding event listener to dinamicly created dom nodes. Check my solution:

```js
$('#gogo').click(function(e){
    var data='<a href="http://wikipedia.org" class="myButtons">Wikipedia</a><a href="http://www.microsoft.com" class="myButtons">Microsoft</a>';
    $("#showResults").html(data);
});


$("body").on("click", ".myButtons", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).attr("href"));
    $("#result").attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="gogo">Click me</button>

<div id="showResults"></div>

<iframe id="result" name="result" src="" width="750px" height="450px" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: thank you, it is working, but iframe doesn't navigate to the desired web, why?

Comment: It's because webpages you have chosen (google/microsoft) block displaying them in iframes on other webpages. Try with different Urls, like Wikipedia.org. I've updated an example.

Comment: thank you, full response +1